# Issue with the space in the path specified for build.xml

Tags: ant, build

I have a build file, which has the following property in it.

```
   <property name="schema.dir" value="src/main/resources/schema" />
```

This schema.dir is used to refer a wsdl file.The parent folder which contains the build.xml has a space in it  like this  **folder name** . 
When I echoed the property it displayed only **src/main/resources/schema**.
But I can see from the ant logs that issue is with the space in the folder name.
Since the parent folder is having a space in it, I am not able to refer the wsdl.

Can somebody suggest a solution so that file can be accessed with out changing the folder name

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to provide directly full path to wsdl file?

Try to replace " " sign with "%20".

For test you can hardcode that and with ANT you can use the [propertyregex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task from Ant Contrib.
See [Replacing characters in Ant property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176071/replacing-characters-in-ant-property)

Comment: It is working at some places, like where we are refering the WSDL file, but it failed for certain cases where I tried to copy the files.
I have used the '<copy file=""/>' command.It returned an error like
_Could not find file /home/interface/projects/Workspace/Interface%20Server/UniServ/Webservices/src/main/resources/schema/IDAuthentication/IDAuthentication.wsdl to copy_

Comment: Please recheck your test with '<copy file=""/>' -> in stack trace that you provided "ma‌​in" string may contain different chars (try to search "ma‌​in" in this page and you will notice). It should be like "'${property with blanks}'"

New idea: try to surround path with ' char -> see [ant java task with space issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747814/ant-java-task-with-space-issue)

Comment: The issue was like I was able to refer a wsdl file from the build file using this path **/home/interface/projects/Workspace/Interface%20Server/UniServ/Webservices/src/main/resources/schema/BizIDVerification/BizIDVerification.wsdl**,  which I modified using the propertyregex task. But the same path failed when I used for a copy task. So I have used the path with out applying the propertyregex ie like this **/home/interface/projects/Workspace/Interface Server/UniServ/Webservices/src/main/resources/schema/BizIDVerification/BizIDVerification.wsdl**, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying your property as a location rather than a string so Ant knows it's dealing with a file path, you can also specify the path as relative to your base directory.

```
<property name="schema.dir" location="${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema"/>
```

Adding **${basedir}** to the path may not be necessary after changing the property from a **value** to a **location**.